# Additional SATA power on PowerEdge T130?

Tags: dell-poweredge, electrical-power, sata

I have a new PowerEdge T130 that came with two SATA drives in RAID 1 setup on a PERC ctrl.  I want to add another SATA drive not connected to the PERC controller.  I opened the case up and see there's *one* SATA data port on the motherboard and *no* SATA power anywhere I can find.

How can I get additional power for the extra SATA drive in the server?  Do I need to split the existing SATA power somehow?  Is there another type of plug I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

Readily built servers have a certain number of bays for drives, some of which may be optional. There are usually no provisions for adding drives outside of these bays.

The T130 supports up to four disks, two in the lower bay, there should be power somewhere.

That said, nobody will stop you from using a 1=>2 power-splitting adapter to provide power for an additional drive. However, this may not be supported by Dell.

Comment: The two disks it came with were pre-installed in the lower bay.  I don't see any addt'l power there.  There seems to be an "upper bay" close to CD drive that's empty.  I also don't see any power there.

Comment: The manual doesn't mention power - the upper cage seems to have a backplane providing power though. (I'm not familiar with that server, just guessing from the manual description.)

Comment: What's a "backplane"  I don't see any plugs hanging off the back.  Is it something I need to buy a plug for and plug in?

Comment: A backplane is a PCB with connectors in the back of a cage that the drives plug into when you insert them. [...] Sorry, my bad - the manual is contradictory (p. 53 vs 56), the T130 doesn't really seem to have a backplane, just an open cage.

Answer (score 0):

I have identical server and solution was. To power fifth disk you will need

1. Order 22 pin male to 22 pin male adapter. E.g https://www.aliexpress.com/item/E-yield-SATA-22-Pin-Male-to-SATA-22-Pin-Male-Adapter/32803156200.html
2. Standard sata cable.
3. SATA F - 2xSATA F E.g (https://www.varle.lt/kompiuteriniai-kabeliai-adapteriai/sata-kabelis-qoltec-sata-2xsata-f2f-20cm--1328703.html) You plug one end to 22 male adapter another end to old disk and other end to new disk or just another power splitter.
4. For sata you can use existing sata slot in the middle of motherboard or buy mini SAS adatapter. Theoretically you should be able to power 5 additional disks without any additional SATA card :) As for power consumption you should check how much power they take.

Dells female 22 pin goes to 22 male adapter. Then to male adapter goes sata cable and Sata Female power cable.

That's all. All works :)

Answer (score 0):

I just added a SATA power connection to the existing cable. By "splicing" in one of these connectors [SATA Power Connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rCSFv.jpg).

And then I used a SATA power female to male splitter to give me the further connections I needed.